# How to debug shader (OpenGL) per pixel in nsight graphic like render doc

Tags: nsight, renderdoc

In renderdoc, It's easy .But this feature doesn't support Opengl

[image]

So I try to use Nsight.

But I don't know how to do can I reproduce this operation in nsight. Its interface is too complex，and I also find nothing useful in introduce document.